# How to use countif and if and round in the same time

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

[image]

From this picture we know the data have mode 3.14
and the value 3.14  = value 3.1 , right?
whereas the value 3.1 its not only 3.14 , but include 3.05, 3.06, 3.07, 3.08, 3.09, 3.10 , 3.11 , 3.12 , 3.13 , and 3.14 right ?

the question is , how to let the count ​​of the formula may appear with the known just mode ?

or whats formula of "if" or "round", if I want to know the count from that value of 3.05, 3.06, 3.07, 3.08, 3.09, 3.10 , 3.11 , 3.12 , 3.13 , and 3.14 was selected from the range of data without having to reduce the decimal point in the data column and without typing the value?

I'm already try =COUNTIF(A2:A22,ROUND(MODE(A2:A22),1)) , but the result = 1 not 6. anybody can help me?

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS` with `>=` and `<`? Like: `=COUNTIFS(A2:A22,">="&ROUND(MODE(A2:A22),1)-0.05,A2:A22,"<"&ROUND(MODE(A2:A22),1)+0.05)`

Comment: that formula can't runing or execute

Comment: does it include 3.15, 3.16, 3.17, 3.19 as well?  or are you looking for 3.10 to 3.14 only?

Comment: not include 3.15, 3.16, 3.17, 3.18, 3.19 , only 3.10 to 3.14

Comment: I don't understand you second sentence in your picture, value 3.14 = value 3.1.  They are not the same value.  If you are trying to say that 3.1 has the same value as 3.05-3.14 for 1 significant digit then yes.  Why are 3.05-3.09 excluded in your third sentence?

Comment: okay, sorry, I realized my mistake . Sorry.
I agree with your statement. if I change so 3.05 to 3.14 , how the formula ?

Comment: @Revaldo please check my formula for hidden characters (it's a known bug at SO that sometimes that happen at comments. (I've found 2x 2 chars `...,A2:A22,"<"&[HERE]ROUND(MODE(A2:A22),1[HERE])+0.05)`

Comment: One reason Dirk's formula may not work for you is also dependent on what version of Excel you have.  COUNTIFS should work as far back as Excel 2007

Comment: thank you so much Dirk Reichel and Forward Ed, it's work. I tried both and work. sorry for making you confuse with my statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A22,"<="&3.14)-COUNTIF(A2:A22,"<"&3.05)
```

count everything equal to or below 3.14, and then subtract everything less than 3.10.

To automate the rounding process, you could go with what Dirk was suggesting and use:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A22,"<"&ROUND(MODE(A2:A22),1)+0.05)-COUNTIF(A2:A22,"<"&ROUND(MODE(A2:A22),1)-0.05)
```

Proof of Concept

[image: POF]

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but all I need its just formula, not typing the value 3.10 to 3.14
and sorry before, I need to revised my question.
correct digit is 3.05 to 3.14 = 3.1

Comment: Did you try the automated formula at the bottom?

Comment: I'm already try, but failed to be execute, appear warning, and pointing at (") before second ROUND

Comment: Probably a typo, the only place you should see the " character is either side of the < symbol.  if you are copying and pasting the formula, make sure you get the whole formula using the scroll bar underneath it.

Comment: your formula works, but Dirk's formula can't work in my excel

oh ya, if you add another number in column 23 : 2.97
your formula cant work

Comment: if you add another number in the column, your range is no longer A2:A22 but instead A2:A23.  You need to adjust your range to suit the number of rows you are analysing.