# How to use Round() in an array formula?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the number of unique values in a range of values *after* the values are rounded to the hundredths place.

This is the formula I am using to count the number of unique values in the range:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($EZ6:$FD6,$EZ6:$FD6&""))
```

and this is what I've tried to count the number of unique values in the range after rounding:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(ROUND($EZ6:$FD6,2),ROUND($EZ6:$FD6,2)&""))
```

This formula produces an error and doesn't evaluate.

The issue isn't adding the `""` at the end, since this formula also produces an error and doesn't evaluate:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(ROUND($EZ6:$FD6,2),ROUND($EZ6:$FD6,2)))
```

By produce an error, I mean that a message box appears saying "There is a problem with this formula..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use countif and if and round in the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39114225/11683)

Comment: I believe that question regards comparing each rounded value in the range to a singular value. My formula must compare a range of rounded values to another range of rounded values.

Comment: The best method would be to do the ROUND in a helper column then use the countif on those helper columns.

Comment: I'd rather not use helper columns for this. Is there like a general methodology for doing things formulaicly rather than in helper columns? Like can you construct an array data structure from a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes unfortunately Countif only works with ranges, not arrays - as soon as you introduce the Round function, you are implicitly using arrays.

I would suggest using the Frequencies method for getting unique values:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(EZ6:FD6<>"",ROUND(EZ6:FD6,2)),ROUND(EZ6:FD6,2))>0))
```

This is based on a standard formula  [see documentation](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273)- the only issue is that if you apply the Round function to blank cells, you get zero, which could give you an extra unique value, hence the If statement.

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>